# Uploading a website when FTP ports are banned

Tags: cpanel, ftp, uploading

I'm a student living in a dormitory. My dormitory banned all FTP related ports. I'm designing websites but I don't know how to upload them without a FTP client or SSH. Is there anyway to upload it? Can a cPanel solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Back in the days I used http://www2ftp.de/ on school, because no FPT Client was installed. It's a web based FTP Client using Port 80 / 443 for it.

Answer (score 3):

Most panels have a File Manager feature that will allow you to upload, download and edit any file on your server. It is very much like a web based FTP client. I know for sure cPanel and Plesk have this tool, so I would assume other will too (since most panels this days try to mimic cPanel and Plesk).

Keep in mind though that if you have to upload/download very large files or thousands of files this web bases solution is less reliable and if transfers get interrupted it’s easier to be left with corrupted uploaded/downloaded files as opposed as when working with an FTP client such as FileZilla which will pause and resume the transfer as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If a web-based portal for uploading like what Guillermo described to you doesn't work and your computer is portable with wifi, then you may want to leave your dormitory and visit a store with free wifi access and see if they allow FTP access.